# Unable to convert whole div to editable form

Tags: javascript, jeditable

I am having a div of basic information and i have a button for edit when user clicks the edit button this Basic information div will be converted into form. I am using  [Jeditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable)!  for this work. But issue is when user clicks on edit button my JavaScript function is invoked and then for editable i have to click on the field to edit but i want with one click form should be visible i do not have to go and click each field. The code for javascript method that is as below

```
            //  alert('ready');
        alert("I Got That All!!!");
        $('#name1').editable(' '
        );
        $('#name1').editable('enable');
        $('#BG1').editable(' ',
        {
            data: " {'1':'O+','2':'O-','3':'A+','4':'A-','5':'B+','6':'B-','7':'AB+','8':'AB-','selected':'1'}",
            type: 'select'
        }
        );
        $('#BG1').editable('enable');
        $('#DOB2').editable('');
        $('#DOB2').editable('enable');
        $('#MS1').editable(' ',
        {   data:  "{'1':'Single','2':'Married','3':'Engaged','selected':'1'}",
            type: 'select'
        }
        );
```

Comment: where did u calling this js ? give us fiddle.

Comment: [here is the code](http://jsfiddle.net/NaveedYousaf/Qg9ww/) you may check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to attach the editable to a custom `event`, say `custom.editable`, and then trigger that same event when user clicks on the edit button (say it's ID is `#edit')

```
$('#edit').on('click', function() {
  $('.editable').trigger('custom.editable');
}
```

And configure your editable area as such:

```
 $('.editable').editable('... path ...', {
   event: 'custom.editable'
   ... more config ...
 }
```

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f2akB/

Comment: can you explain me about this line of code what is this doing '         $('.edit').trigger('editing.custom');'

Comment: yes, see accoring to Jeditable's documentation, you can bind any event with triggering the form's editable functionality. By default, it is bound to 'click', but you can bind anything. Here I've bound it to the `editing.custom`. This is just a custom event I thought of.

Now, when you click on the button, you need to somehow **manufacture** this event on that element so that the element becomes editable, that's why I used the `trigger`. It is used to manually create an event. See it's jquery documentation for more details.